# Why ifdown of alias remove my main interface?

Tags: networking, ip, alias, ethernet

I have interface eth0 defined on my computer and alias eth0: 1 related to it

```
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr X:5D:X:3F:X:89  
          inet addr:X.X.0.156  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:X.X.X.X
          inet6 addr: X::9a5d:X:fe3f:X/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:677 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:56767 (55.4 KiB)  TX bytes:16019 (15.6 KiB)
          Interrupt:175 

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr X:5D:X:3F:X:89   
          inet addr:X.X.0.181  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:X.X.X.X
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:175
```

but when I just want to disable an alias with the command below it deletes eth0 as well.

```
/sbin/ifdown eth0:1
```

Why is this happening?

On the other hand, if it tries to disable an alias with a command, it works and removes itself:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 down
```

But when I restore the alias again, my situation is as below

```
# /sbin/ifup eth0:1
ifup: interface eth0:1 already configured
# /sbin/ifdown eth0:1
# /sbin/ifup eth0:1

# ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr X:5D:X:3F:X:89  
          inet6 addr: X::9a5d:X:fe3f:X/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1321 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:235 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:111766 (109.1 KiB)  TX bytes:20421 (19.9 KiB)
          Interrupt:175 

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr X:5D:X:3F:X:89   
          inet addr:X.X.0.181  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:X.X.X.X
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:175
```

Eth0 loses its IP address and settings. Which may cause me to not be able to delete and set the alias individually?

The / etc / network / interfaces file has eth0 and eth0: 1 defined

```
# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address X.X.0.156
    netmask X.X.X.X
    gateway X.X.0.1

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address X.X.0.181
    netmask X.X.X.X
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumming your subnetmasks are equal:

At least linux kernel 4.19 has a bug regarding your observation.
Adding 2 IP addresses in the same subnet to one interface and deleting the first one, will delete both:

```
    ifconfig eth0 1.1.1.1/24
    ifconfig eth0:2 1.1.1.2/24
    ifconfig eth0 0
```

But remember that this is still a misconfiguration to have 2 IP addresses of the same subnet on one interface. It will listen to both ip addresses but the answering ip address is not specified. Use this configuration only temporarily.
Linux kernel 5.10 deletes the correct ip address in this situation.

Comment: that's not a bug: the alias *address* (and not the fiction of interface) is a secondary IP address when set in the same IP LAN: when the primary IP address is deleted, all secondary IP addresses are also deleted, including the alias. That's documented (documented in how to prevent it: 4.19: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=v4.19#n1292 . Didn't change in 5.10: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v5.10#n1557 )